# BAT for renaming a CSV file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

SAP Business Object  produces monthly a CSV file and stores it in a specific folder under a server. No problem with that.

The file name looks like this: `NN_EXPORTNAME_XXXXXXXXXXX`
Where X is an alphanumeric character.
Where N is a numeric character

I would like a bat that renames that file after its "production". The file is generated in the first working day of the month and contains data for the previous one (EG. on the first day of November BO will produce an export with the data of October).

The BAT I need has to change the characters **after** the `_` with the correct month in the `MMYYYY` format. E.g.: I create the file for November, it needs to be renamed as `NN_EXPORTNAME_102016`

Comment: ...and what is the cmd output of `echo %date%` on your computer?

Comment: echo %date% on my computer is 02/11/2016 (DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: Use my script below,  I have updated it to suit the format you have reported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method; there are many assumptions.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR/B/OD/A-D ?*_?*_?*.csv') DO (
    SET "MyCSV=%%~nA")
SET/A "LstMon=1%DATE:~-7,2%-1"
SET "NewEnd=%LstMon:~-2%%DATE:~-4%"
FOR %%A IN (%MyCSV:_= %) DO SET "OldEnd=%%A"
CALL REN "%MyCSV%.csv" "%%MyCSV:_%OldEnd%=%%_%NewEnd%.csv"
```

The script should be in the same directory as the CSV to work on double click.

Comment: I have not clear which should I put in DIR/B/OD7A-D
Should I also insert the current name of the CSV file "MyCSV"?

Comment: You've already provided the name format for your CSV in your question, my answer doesn't need changing to suit it, I have already catered for your file name format.